# Software for recognizing algebraic or D-finite formal power series

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, computation

I have a formal power series in one variable that I think might be algebraic (or perhaps just D-finite). Is there software that could help me explore this?

By way of comparison, there’s a very simple way to see if a formal power series appears to be rational: for small values of $n$, compute the determinant of the $(n+1)$-by-$(n+1)$ Hankel matrix whose entries are the first $2n+1$ coefficients of the formal power series. If the determinant is 0, then nontrivial elements of the nullspace correspond to possible $n$th order recurrence relations.

(I’m including the combinatorics tag since this sort of pattern-finding is sometimes an important early step in a combinatorial research project.)

Comment: I have written a Maple library that takes a sequence and tries to conjecture an algebraic, D-finite, or D-algebraic expression for it. It's not quite polished enough for a public release yet, but I would be happy to run it on your series for you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Jay! The sequences I’m curious about are

18, 142, 1266, 12030, 118650, 1198230, 12296202, 127633590, 1336133730, 14079114270, 149124688482, 1586159072814, 16929780310218, 181227223899942, 1944808008842490, 20915277691567206, ...

and

84, 724, 6516, 60900, 586404, 5777916, 57952212, 589381020, 6060195316, 62863155972, 656765033268, 6902094928308, 72892778268996, 773013952508268, 8226672021670804,...

Comment: I wasn't able to make any guesses, but that is not uncommon with this few terms. Any chance you have more?

Comment: The listtorec function in the gfun package in Maple  tries to find a P-recursion for a sequence and listtodiffeq tries to find a differential equation.  They do not succeed in your examples. See https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=gfun.

Comment: There are some earlier terms, but they do not follow the same 2-adic periodicity that later terms do, so I’m not sure they’ll be helpful: 3, 18, 142, 1266, ... and 1, 10, 84, 724, 6516, ...

Comment: Still no guesses, unfortunately. In order to guess an algebraic generating function $p(F,x) = 0$ with degree $m$ in $F$ and degree $d$ in $x$, my library needs at least $(m+1)(d+1)+1$ terms.

Comment: Alas, the software I’m using isn’t able to handle larger numbers than that (and even if it were reconfigured to handle larger numbers the running time would become unacceptably long). But thanks for trying!

Comment: Could you include the algorithm that generated the sequences? It might be relevant

Comment: It’s software David DesJardins wrote for counting tilings. At some point I’ll write something about the problem and submit the sequences to OEIS, and I’ll add links here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fricas is good at that. It can be accessed via sage, once installed.

```
sage: L=[catalan_number(i) for i in range(20)]                                  
sage: fricas.guessHolo(L)                                                       
[
     n           2      ,
  [[x ]f(x): (4 x  - x)f (x) + (2 x - 1)f(x) + 1 = 0,

                     2      3      4
   f(x) = 1 + x + 2 x  + 5 x  + O(x )]
  ]
sage:
```

and also

```
sage: fricas.guessAlg(L)                                                        
    n             2                                   2      3      4
[[[x ]f(x): x f(x)  - f(x) + 1 = 0, f(x) = 1 + x + 2 x  + 5 x  + O(x )]]
```

Comment: If I'm doing it right, [doesn't](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVULtOBEEM65H4hy1BQqvEmbwKCjqK-wNEceJxQjpxEif-H890FJvMeGzH2cPjy6b1sOkACyJmFRM2rfDVu7AAoAOyeBlm3hM0C365CEOylU65Lq0YUTVqKrxCKUiUDl6j0VliKljTi-YJWHX3StJjlJQI9RhzEKTVkRlskRAG3fd9O36_b0XHBEu4Eg5poYAThxD0TKaKeWgHFPOprThaJjlE220JUWHq3onpFcn9zRAMGE12j0aZ1JxWzSzFt24qk_ur0d6lFr_AX8mU0EiuMV5vbz5_vt6O1_30-3G9Pl_Ol7vD_fYffTqfCP4BTj1UnA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) know [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393214/software-for-recognizing-algebraic-or-d-finite-formal-power-series#comment1003774_393214).

Comment: (The [previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393214/software-for-recognizing-algebraic-or-d-finite-formal-power-series#comment1004402_393221) was very terse because the links were very long. )

Comment: Sagecell does not have fricas. You need to do "sage -i fricas" in your own installation of sagemath.

Comment: There is a [sandbox](http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl/SandBox) for fricas, but it seems it cannot handle these sequences.

Comment: Once you have sage installed, `sage -i fricas` installs fricas.

Comment: There is an option you can pa to `guessAlg` and the others, which will try all combinations of coefficient degrees.  For example, it will try $p_0(x) + p_1(x) f(x) + \dots + p_k(x) f^k(x)$, for $\sum deg(p_i)$ determined by the amount of input data.  Of course this takes a long time.  Unfortunately, even with this option turned on, it couldn't find a relation.